# Reading input via System.in.read()

Tags: java, input, do-while

I'm experimenting a little bit with console input.

As of System.in.read() is concerned, I've so far understood that 
1. it reads characters from the keyboard
2. it stores them as integer values i.e. a cast is required 
3. it is line buffered i.e. it reads any character until ENTER is hit.

Now I'm trying to understand what actually happens when I want to read a single character like so

```
do
{
char ch, answer = 'C', ignore; 
System.out.println("Try to guess the correct letter"); 

ch = (char) System.in.read(); 

// discard any characters in the input buffer 

do 
{
ignore = (char) System.in.read(); 
}
while(ignore != '\n'); 

if(answer == ch) System.out.println("Right"); 
}
while(answer != ch);
```

I stumbled upon this snippet and after inserting a print statement I've grasped that although I intend to read a single character the method would read any  character typed until I hit the enter key.

So, with the second loop I would discard any letters that are entered after the first one, until the ENTER key is hit, right?

I am aware of the effect caused by leaving out the second do-while loop: The carriage return would be checked against a given if-condition. But how does it work that the first method call would truly result in only reading a character and the second one in reading all the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Because the second loop doesn't call `read` just once, but calls its repeatedly,  once each time through the loop, each call reading a single character, until it gets to the end of the line.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Sure, we are talking about a loop.

Comment: Like when I for example, read an 'A' and hit enter. What would actually happen? Would I read the A, jump to the second loop, and continue reading until ENTER is hit?

Comment: That's what your program would do, yes.

Comment: So: The method System.in.read() would open the input stream and just read a character from it?